# React 0.13 class method undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So i've started with React and ES6 and got stuck with very basics. Really appreciate some help.

handleClick() throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined
```

code follows

```
export default class MenuItems extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {active: false}
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
  }

  render() {
    let active = this.state.active
    let menuItems = [{text: 'Logo'}, {text:  'promo'}, {text:     'benefits'}, { text: 'form'}]
    return (
      <ul>
        {menuItems.map(function(item) {
          return <li className={active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{menuItems.map(function(item) {
  return <li className={active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>;
})}
```

Because your code is in strict mode (modules are always in strict mode),  `this` is `undefined` inside the function you pass to `.map`.

You either have to explicitly set the context by passing a [second argument to `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
{menuItems.map(function(item) {
  // ...
}, this)}
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
{menuItems.map(
     item => <li className={active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
)}
```

Comment: That do helped me thank you. One more thing — why 'active' is added to all li's? Expected behavior was only adding to one.

Comment: *"Expected behavior was only adding to one."* You have a single `active` variable for all `li` elements. You either have to give every `li` there own state (make them their own component), or store something that identifies the active `li` element, not just `true` and `false`. Btw, since your binding `handleClick` inside the constructor, `onClick={this.handleClick}` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

`react.js:18794 Warning: bind():` You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See BlueBall

so just like this:

```
{
  menuItems.map(
     item => <li className={active ? 'active' : ''} 
  onClick={this.handleClick} key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
)}
```